# Displaying multiple images with single <img> tag

Tags: java, html, scriptlet

I have a path of set of images in in the form of array of strings (display). Now I am trying to display all my images in html page. But no success.

```
<div class="result-display-class">
            <%
               String[] display = (String[])request.getAttribute("images");

                if (display != null && display.length != 0)
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<display.length; i++)
                    {
                        out.println(display[i]);
                     %>   
                     <img src="display[i]" alt="facebook" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                     <%
                    }
                }
            %>  
        </div>
```

Could you please suggest how can I do that? It is displayinh alt value for all images. Path is verified.

Comment: Have you inspected what the browser is seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an inline scriptlet:

```
<img src="<%= display[i] %>" alt="facebook" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
```